# Mysql JSON_MERGE_PATCH is replacing first json completely

Tags: mysql, sql

This expample from [Mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_merge_patch/):

```
SET @json1 = '[1, 2]';
SET @json2 = '[2, 3]';
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH(@json1,@json2),JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@json1,@json2);
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| JSON_MERGE_PATCH(@json1,@json2) | JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@json1,@json2) |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| [2, 3]                          | [1, 2, 2, 3]                       |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I would like the result to be:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Where it adds 'none' exist values. How?
Is there other functions to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_merge_patch/) on `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` is not very descriptive, as it simply states:

> JSON_MERGE_PATCH is an RFC 7396-compliant replacement for JSON_MERGE

However, [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch) explains it pretty well:

> Performs an RFC 7396 compliant merge of two or more JSON documents and returns the merged result, without preserving members having duplicate keys.
>
> JSON_MERGE_PATCH() performs a merge as follows:
>
> a. If the first argument is not an object, the result of the merge is
>   the same as if an empty object had been merged with the second
>   argument.
>
> b. If the second argument is not an object, the result of the merge
>   is the second argument.

Now, in your case you are trying to merge two JSON arrays, but not objects. So as per the point **b** above, the result of the merge is the second argument, and hence you are getting the second array, *i.e.*, `[2, 3]`.

On the other hand, [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) for `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` states the following:

> Merges two or more JSON documents and returns the merged result.
>
> Merging takes place according to the following rules.
>
> - Adjacent arrays are merged to a single array.

That is why, when you use `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE`, you get both the arguments (arrays) merged into a single array, *i.e.*, `[1, 2, 2, 3]`

Comment: So, I can't get the result I want somehow?

Comment: @Dohab I tried various ways but could not find any :( Best bet is to use `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` and then get the result in PHP and run `array_unique()` on it (if you are using PHP); other programming languages would also have similar methods.